# How to shorten a url helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are a lot of SO questions on this but none of them was able to answer what I was looking for. Please let me know if I am wrong.

I have following routes in my route files

```
namespace :integrations do
  resources :google, only: [] do
    collection do
      get 'prompt'
      get 'callback'
    end
  end
end
```

These creates very long url helpers like below.

```
prompt_integrations_google_index GET        /integrations/google/prompt(.:format)            integrations/google#prompt
callback_integrations_google_index GET        /integrations/google/callback(.:format)          integrations/google#callback
```

I've tried using `as` but that doesn't work. I don't know if using `path` is the right way. How can I shorten their helper name?

Ex:
`google_prompt_integrations_google_index -> google_prompt`

I would like to do the renaming for just one selected route and keep all others unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way with `as`

```
 namespace :integrations, as: '' do
     resource :google, only: [:prompt, :callback] do
       collection do
         get 'prompt', as: 'prompt'
         get 'callback', as: 'cb'
       end
     end
   end
```

On rake routes we get `prompt_google` and `cb_google`

```
#rake routes

prompt_google GET    /integrations/google/prompt(.:format)   integrations/googles#prompt
cb_google GET    /integrations/google/callback(.:format) integrations/googles#callback
```

*Update:*

In the case you want to just change 1 route why not have something like

```
get 'integrations/google/prompt', to: 'integrations/google#prompt', as: 'google_prompt'
```

rake routes will return

```
 google_prompt GET    /integrations/google/prompt(.:format)   integrations/google#prompt
```

Comment: Yes, what you suggest will work, but now my other routes in `google` resources will miss the `integrations` prefix which I would not want to happen.

Comment: Just having the ability to rename helper for one route? Anything like that exists?

Comment: I realized google is a single resource. Updating resources to resource will give what you need.

Comment: `only: [:prompt, :callback]` has no impact.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Added just for readability that it has only 2 actions. Yes, it does not do anything.

Comment: @aks doing both implementation in the same block is not feasible. If you want to treat just 1 route differently have it as a separate route pointing to action. Updated my answer for same

Answer (score 0):

You can write the route definition as:

```
namespace :integrations, as: '' do
  resource :google, only: [] do
    collection do
      get 'prompt'
      get 'callback'
    end
  end
end
```

And then add the below inflections to remove `_index` with helper. `_index` comes from this [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d7b17dfa0258dfbe387a1dfffa590c8d343db6e9/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1186-L1188)

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^(google)$/i, '\1s'
  inflect.singular /^(google)s/i, '\1'
end
```

Now you get as you want:

```
$ rails routes | grep google
        prompt_google GET    /integrations/google/prompt(.:format)          integrations/googles#prompt
      callback_google GET    /integrations/google/callback(.:format)        integrations/googles#callback
```

Comment: Just a question where would we write the inflictions?

Comment: I would still want my other resources in google to have the integration prefix. Will that be possible?

Comment: @aks You should mention that too in the question then before ? :)

Comment: I'm really sorry. I would do that. ;)

Comment: @aks "I would still want my other resources in google to have the integration prefix. Will that be possible?" - Not possible. You have only 1 choice, I don't think it can be mixed. I would suggest then to create those routes outside the `resources` method.

Comment: I don't think we need the initializer. It works without that too. Check my answer.

Comment: @AnkitG Without the inflection `_index` can't be removed. Your one worked as you used `resource` not `resources`. :) OP has `resources :google`, so I was following him.